# Storing multiple foreach loops into a array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

```
foreach (array_chunk($html->find('div[class=yemek]'), 4, true) as $array) {
    echo '///';
    foreach($array as $ul) {
        foreach($ul->find('img') as $li) {
            echo $li->alt . ',';
        }
    }
}
```

I want to store the last result into an array. I have no idea since there is 2 foreach loop. Is it possible? Or I have something in my mind.

Comment: last of which foreach????

Answer (score 0):

assign to the same variable each step, at last you will just the last value.

```
$last = '';
foreach (array_chunk($html->find('div[class=yemek]'), 4, true) as $array) {
echo '///';
foreach($array as $ul) {
       foreach($ul->find('img') as $li)  {
          echo $li->alt . ',';
       }

}
}
$lastArray = [$last];
```

Comment: I can't use it in my function? someFunction($lastArray);

Comment: what's your someFunction??

Comment: `function tweet($message) {
    require_once('./codebird.php');
          \Codebird\Codebird::setConsumerKey("1","2");
 $cb = \Codebird\Codebird::getInstance();
          $cb->setToken("1","2");
 
    $params = array(
      'status' => $message
    );
    $reply = $cb->statuses_update($params);
 }`

Comment: what the parameter type statuses_update expect? one-dimension array? or two.

Comment: Only one just like a string.

Comment: Why you give it a two dimension array

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean? when I use tweet(test); It works fine.

Comment: @RıdvanÇetin how can you use tweet(test), what the test here??  is it not tweet('test')

Comment: here it only accept string, but you call it with a two dimension array at the parameter, how can it works?